# Firebase Query to filter data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure looks like this ,

```
-posts
    -postId1
        -tags
            1:A
            2:B
            3:D
        -text:Hello

    -postId2
        -tags
            1:B
            2:D
        -text:How are you?

    -postId3
        -tags   
            1:A
            2:C
        -text:Hello World
```

Now, I want to retrieve the text of those postIds which contains tags B or D, Which one will be the best approach to achieve this ?

Comment: You might be interested in this post[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/)

Comment: This is a categorization problem. See my answer here for one way to solve that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value